# How to know the threshold value when using the Open CV adaptiveThreshold() method?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

When using OpenCV's `adaptiveThreshold()` method , it returns only the image. But I want to know the used threshold value (like in the fixed `thresholdvalue()` method). Any idea of how to get that?

Comment: This function uses a different threshold for each pixel. The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#adaptivethreshold) explains exactly how these thresholds are computed, and you should be able to reproduce that using the functions linked in it. Please let us know what is not clear.

Comment: It's not clear for me how to reproduce that. Can you explain a little bit about it ? I'm fairly new to image processing and openCV.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in [the documentation to `adaptiveThreshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#adaptivethreshold), the output is obtained by thresholding each pixel with a different value. These values are obtained by one of two methods, depending on the value of the parameter `adaptiveMethod`:

```
output = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(input, 255, adaptiveMethod, THRESH_BINARY, blockSize, C);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if adaptiveMethod == cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C:
    T = cv2.blur(input, blockSize);
else: # adaptiveMethod == cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C
    T = cv2.GaussianBlur(input, blockSize);
T -= C;
output = input > T;
```

Note that `>` by default sets the output to 255 if the condition is true, this is why I selected `255` as value for the `maxValue` parameter to `adaptiveThreshold`.

[I have not run the code above, but am reasonably sure it works as advertised. Please comment if there are any issues.]